# Updating multiple Google Sheets from a template sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to create a template sheet, that I can then make edits to the structure and template of this sheet, and push all of the edits to multiple sheets built from the original template sheet?

I have created vendor dashboards in Google Sheets for all of our partner vendors, and rather than having to make any change to all of the vendor sheets individually, I'd like to be able to have one template that gets updated, and when I'm ready, I can release it out to all of the other sheets.

For example, if I'd like to add a column for the vendor to update us on a status of a shipment, rather than creating that column in all of the vendor sheets, it would be nice to update it one place (the template) and then release it to all of the vendor sheets.

Answer (score 0):

depends, but (maybe) yes:

- create your template in your master sheet
- import your template in all vendors sheets like 
  `=IMPORTRANGE("url-of-your-sheet-or-id","Sheet1!A1:C")`
- then import back column from vendors' sheet into your sheet
   `=IMPORTRANGE("url-of-vendor-sheet-or-id","Sheet1!D2:D")`
- now you are under control of columns **A:C** which has your template and all comments vendor does in his **D2:D** column are visible in your master sheet

**note:** there could be a lot of limitations, hence all depends on your template complexity